# Pacemaker custom resource agent does not execute script on failover

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I am implementing a test cluster with 2 nodes.
I want to execute my script  when failover occours.
I create my resource fro Dummy RA named "script".
When I test with the command "pcs resource debug-start script" it works.
But when failover occurs, pacemaker send the resource to other node but the script doesn't run as in the test.
I modified th RA Dummy adding the script path as follow:

```
failOverScript_start() {
    failOverScript_monitor
    if [ $? =  $OCF_SUCCESS ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/ScriptTest.sh
        return $OCF_SUCCESS
    fi
```

The script is in right path and has all permissions. Could someone help me please?
Thanks